# Reliable way to get push notifications on android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, sleep-mode

For my application it is important to receive notifications in time when server sends them. However (I guess due deep sleep of phone) some notifications are received with a huge delay.

I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging. I creaed a simple open source app for testing reliable push notifications: https://github.com/solvek/ReliableFCM

**The message type is [Data Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages) (not Notifications)**

While sending the message I set priority to `high`

Is there any way all my users (regardless their android version and device model) receive notification in the time when it is sent by server?

Tested receiving push notifications over night and these are the results:
[image]

My service

```
class FcmService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
    super.onNewToken(token)
    Timber.tag(TAG).d("Firebase token:$token")
}

override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message)
    val data = message.data
    val reliableId = data["reliableId"]
    val time = reliableId!!.toLong().formatTime()
    Timber.tag(TAG).i("========= Received a push (id $reliableId, type ${data["type"]} time $time priority ${message.priority})")
    if (data.getBool("network", true)){
        networkOperation()
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ReliableFCM"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <service
        android:name=".FcmService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ReliableFCM">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Are you setting the messages to [high priority](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/message-priority)?

Comment: Yes, high priority is set